# 400 bad request when submitting form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, form-submit

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting a `400 bad request`. Before I got `400 bad request`, the form had `"id"` instead of `"name"`. When the form had `"id"` I got 200 but didn't update my database. Now, I get the error and nothing seems to be working.

Here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(MemberVO vo, Model model) {
    System.out.println(vo);
   logger.info("regist post...");
   logger.info(vo.toString());

   try {

    mservice.insertMember(vo);


   } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
   }
      return "/register_success";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void registrationGet(MemberVO vo, Model model) {


}
```

Here's my form:

```
  <form role = "form" method ="post">        

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" name = "username" placeholder="Email"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name = "password" placeholder="Password"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "firstname" placeholder="firstname"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "lastname" placeholder="lastname"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "phonenum" placeholder="Phone Number"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>                                    

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "birthday" placeholder="Birthday, ex) 1986-06-08"  required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "destination" placeholder="where would you like to go?" required/>
         <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>

    <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-block">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: you should paste the code of  **MemberVO**

Comment: I can't see form action in your html code.

Comment: Code says GET, HTML says POST

Answer (score 1):

We can not tell you the exact problem as you have not attached your modal class `MemberVO`  but you can check below.

1.There is **no action attribute** in your `form`.

2.Ensure that all the fields present in Modal class should also be present in the form **with the same name.**